# Neatly packaging a C++/CLI DLL dependent on lots of native DLLs

Tags: c++, .net, interop, c++-cli

I have created a C++/CLI DLL that is dependent on many native DLLs. I want a way of packaging the .NET DLL with native DLLs for reuse in other projects. Is there a neat way of doing this?

Or is it simply a matter of packaging all the DLLs as a zip and when someone wants to reuse they have to unzip into a folder accessible by the new project reference the .NET DLL and add the native DLLs to the project with "Copy Always" set.

Lets assume we cannot rebuild the C++/CLI using static libraries in lieu of the DLLs.

Comment: Have you considered creating an Installer?

Comment: You answered your question in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I would try somehow having your installer load your .net assembly
In the GAC and your type library with the regasm. This will be dependent on your version of the .Net framework